# Autoware LGSVL fork docker build failed due to "unauthenticated packages"

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error message is as below:

```
E: There were unauthenticated packages and -y was used without --allow-unauthenticated
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y ros-kinetic-desktop-full ros-kinetic-nmea-msgs ros-kinetic-nmea-navsat-driver ros-kinetic-sound-play ros-kinetic-jsk-visualization ros-kinetic-grid-map ros-kinetic-gps-common' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

My environment is

- Ubuntu 16/04
- ROS Kinetic
- Autoware lgsvl fork: https://github.com/lgsvl/Autoware.git

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326151/autoware-lgsvl-fork-docker-build-failed-due-to-%22unauthenticated-packages%22/) by [xpharry](https://answers.ros.org/users/41304/xpharry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're likely running into #q325039.

Please follow the steps there, run `sudo apt update` and then try again.

---

Edit: seeing as this is a Docker build: the author/maintainer of `lgsvl/Autoware` is not basing his builds on the official OSRF docker images. He's importing the repository keys himself ([here](https://github.com/lgsvl/Autoware/blob/4fdb2f8d1aa87ca28f1f4f6a47bf2bf27951a7d5/docker/96boards/Dockerfile.kinetic#L41) fi), which requires updates to the `Dockerfile`s to use the new key

Note that upstream (ie: `autowarefoundation/autoware`) has already changed things significantly and might not have this problem ([these files](https://github.com/autowarefoundation/autoware/tree/42aba1468490e2ed218f9295ab3e7490db864e54/docker)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xpharry](https://answers.ros.org/users/41304/xpharry/) on 2019-06-18**:
I replaced Line 46 in Dockerfile.kinetic with

```
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
```

It seems to be building well now. They should update it.

Thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-18**:\

> They should update it.

you can always submit a pull request.

If you're using the software, it may be nice to do that.

**Comment by [xpharry](https://answers.ros.org/users/41304/xpharry/) on 2019-06-18**:
Will do. Thanks.